# Part of the name of a JSON structure should be dynamic (Apex)

Tags: apex, json

I have a method that receives a large and complicated JSON. The definitions of some of it's parts are:

```
public class LanguageSpecifics {
    public String description;
}
public class I18N {
    public LanguageSpecifics en;
    public LanguageSpecifics nl;
    public LanguageSpecifics de;
    public LanguageSpecifics fr;
    public LanguageSpecifics pl;
    public LanguageSpecifics es;
    public LanguageSpecifics it;
    public LanguageSpecifics ro;
    public LanguageSpecifics bg;
    public LanguageSpecifics fi;
    public LanguageSpecifics se;
}
```

The code in which I want to use this:

```
I18N i = (I18N)JSON.deserialize('{"en": {"description": "english descr"}, "de": {"description": "deutsch"}}', I18N.class);
System.debug(i.en.description);
System.debug(i.de.description);
...
```

What I want to make dynamic, is the language part. My ultimate goal is to be able to do something like this:

```
String l = 'en';
System.debug(i.get(l).description);
```

But I can't get it to work. `i.get(l)` is illegal: the compiler complains: `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(String) from the type I18N`

For normal objects and fields, this would be a valid construction in Apex.

The (much more nested and complicated) JSON has already been deserialized before this method is called, so I don't see how I can use something like `JSON.deserializeUntyped()`. And I really don't want to re-serialize my JSON and then do a `JSON.deserializeUntyped()`

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, to be dynamic, you need a map. You didn't share what the level above looks like, but *that* level needs to have `I18N` defined as:

```
public Map<String, LanguageSpecifics> I18N;
```

Instead of:

```
public I18N I18N;
```

*(Replace the variable name with whatever it is in the code.)*

Then, you'd be able to access it as you desire:

```
data.I18N.get('en');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no influence on the structure/definition of the JSON classes. Trying this: Map<String, LanguageSpecifics> i2 = (Map<String, LanguageSpecifics>)i; gives the error: Incompatible types since an instance of I18N is never an instance of Map<String,LanguageSpecifics> But I guess you already knew that.

Comment: @SanderdeJong Unfortunately, Apex is just limited that way. We don't have java.lang.reflect or any other strongly-typed dynamic language features, and we don't have loosely-typed language dynamic access like JavaScript. If you can't change the JSON classes, you can't access the data dynamically without additional post-processing, as demonstrated in Adrian's answer, or with another JSON serialize/deserialize roundtrip, as you postulated in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this model relatively easy to interact with by adding a lazy loaded map.

```
public class I18N
{
    /*other attributes*/
    public Map<String, String> descriptions
    {
        get
        {
            if (descriptions== null)
            {
                descriptions= new Map<String, String>
                {
                    'en' => en?.description,
                    'nl' => nl?.description,
                    'de' => de?.description
                    //etc.
                };
            }
            return descriptions;
        }
        private set;
    }
}
```

Then once you've deserialized, you can just dynamically retrieve from that map.

```
I18N data = (I18N)JSON.deserialize(...);
String englishDescription = data.descriptions.get('en');
```

Comment: I tried to compile this, but I got the error: Variable does not exist: en LINE: 12 COLUMN: 29

Comment: The comment `/*other attributes*/` was meant to indicate you are not supposed to remove the attributes you already have...